# Understanding Nested Callback Execution Sequence

Tags: javascript, callback, nested

Beginner here trying to wrap his head around nested callbacks.

On this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) there is an example given of how chaining several asynchronous functions together would (in the past) require this infamous callback pyramid of doom:

```javascript
    doSomething(function(result) {
      doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
       doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
        console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
       }, failureCallback);
      }, failureCallback);
    }, failureCallback);
```

Alright so I’m just trying to wrap my head around this and I can’t let it go.

As far as I can understand, I’m looking at a `doSomething()` higher order function call, which has an (anonymous) callback function declared as its parameter, which in turn contains a second function call `doSomethingElse()`, which has another (anonymous) callback function declared as a parameter, containing a call to a third function `doThirdThing()`… and so on.

In short, there are three nested function calls here: `doSomething()`, `doSomethingElse()` and `doThirdThing()`. Each of these has an anonymous function declared as an input parameter.

In order to grasp how this would work, I’ve tried to code my own “pyramid of doom”, without any parameters of failure callbacks to keep it simple:

```javascript
    function someThing() {
        console.log("Do Something!");
    }
    
    function someThingElse () {
      console.log("Do Something Else!");
    }
    
    function doThirdThing () {
      console.log("Do Third thing!");
    }
    
    someThing(function(){
      console.log("First anonymous callback!");
      someThingElse(function(){
        console.log("Second anonymous callback!")
        doThirdThing(function() {
          console.log("Third anonymous callback!");
        })
      })
    })
```

When I run this code all that is being printed to the console is `Do Something!`.

I cannot understand why `someThingElse` and `doThirdThing` are not being run, nor any of the anonymous callback functions??

What am I missing here? Please help!

Comment: Your test functions never actually invoke (or even declare) the functions that are passed as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Your functions fail to take a callback argument, and fails to actually *call* it on completion. ie, this does not work by some magic, you need to actually call the functions.

```js
function someThing(callback) {
    console.log("Do Something!");
    callback();
}

function someThingElse (callback) {
  console.log("Do Something Else!");
  callback();
}

function doThirdThing (callback) {
  console.log("Do Third thing!");
  callback();
}

someThing(function(){
  console.log("First anonymous callback!");
  someThingElse(function(){
    console.log("Second anonymous callback!")
    doThirdThing(function() {
      console.log("Third anonymous callback!");
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `someThing( ... )`, but you are passing it a function, right? However, the declaration `function someThing()` takes no argument. So it does nothing with what you pass it.

You need your functions declarations to take an argument (another function, that will be the callback), then execute it :

```js
function someThing(callback) {
    console.log("Do Something!");
    callback();
}

function someThingElse (callback) {
  console.log("Do Something Else!");
  callback();
}

function doThirdThing (callback) {
  console.log("Do Third thing!");
  callback();
}

someThing(function(){
  console.log("First anonymous callback!");
  someThingElse(function(){
    console.log("Second anonymous callback!")
    doThirdThing(function() {
      console.log("Third anonymous callback!");
    })
  })
})
```